# Combine PHP array as something

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays:

```
$arr1= array("A","B","C");
$arr2= array("1","2","3");
```

Output i need as:

```
$arr3= array("A","1","B","2","C","3");
```

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your first two arrays has the same length, you can use a **loop** to get the array you want:

```
<?PHP
$arr1= array("A","B","C");
$arr2= array("1","2","3");
$arr3=[];
for($i = 0; $i < count($arr1); $i++)
    array_push($arr3, $arr1[$i], $arr2[$i]);
?>
```

It will return:

**$arr3= array("A","1","B","2","C","3");**

Comment: Thanks for the answer & not like others who mind answering any easy question.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [array_merge()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

```
array_merge ( array $array1 [, array $... ] )
```

> Merges the elements of one or more arrays together so that the values
>   of one are appended to the end of the previous one. It returns the
>   resulting array.
>
> If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the later value
>   for that key will overwrite the previous one. If, however, the arrays
>   contain numeric keys, the later value will not overwrite the original
>   value, but will be appended.

Answer (score 0):

This will work to combine the two arrays together:

```
$output = $array1 + $array2;
```

Answer (score 0):

This snippet could solve what you asked, also if arrays are not equal in length.

```
function array_interpolation($arr1, $arr2) {
    $result = array();
    $len1 = count($arr1);
    $len2 = count($arr2);
    $maxlen = max($len1, $len2);
    for($i = 0; $i < $maxlen; $i++) {
        if($i < $len1) {
            array_push($result, $arr1[$i]);
        }
        if($i < $len2) {
            array_push($result, $arr2[$i]);
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```